# Getting Illegal Argument Exception: addAppToken Invalid stackId while launching a activity

Tags: java, android, stack, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to open an Activity from another Activity using the flag CLEAR_TASK, but sometimes I am getting an exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addAppToken: invalid stackId=1

It's a intermittent issue and is not happening every time.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

startActivity(intent1);
```

My ActivityA is a SingleInstance and ActivityB is a SingleTask.

Comment: Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent1);

My ActivityA is SingleInstance and ActivityB is SingleTask.

Comment: @MohitRaheja it is better to add your code editing your post than adding in comments.

Answer (score 0):

> If set in an Intent passed to `Context.startActivity()`, this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: It's working fine on Lollipop but giving exception only on Kitkat devices as well as it's an intermittent issue. Can't reproduce it each and every time.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.

Answer (score 0):

I found same error like you.and finally i knew why,just because i start same activity twice at same time.

but there something bothers me.

i develop a launcher app,this error only occurred when i boot or reboot my device,after i exited my app,then restart it,everything runs good,even this wrong code still there.